# Updating a displayed variable every second with Clock.schedule_interval

Tags: python, kivy

I have schedule_interval calling a function that fetches weather data from the web and then parses it into a dict. I have my kv file reading that dict and displaying values in a floatlayout. I know the function is being called because I am having it print to the console also, but it is not updating in the floatlayout window. I thought the values would automatically update from what I have read.

```
GUI.py
class weather(FloatLayout):
    def w(self):
        a = parse()
        print(a)
        return a

class weatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        d = weather()
        Clock.schedule_interval(d.w, 1)
        return d

weather.kv
<Layout>:
     DragLabel:
        font_size: 600
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos: 415,455
        text: str(root.w()['temp0'])
```

This is just one of the labels. I am very new to Kivy so
if this looks atrocious to you experienced kivy 
people, I apologize.

The print(a) part of def w(self): works every second, but the window does not display the new variables.

```
test.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

a = {}
a['num'] = 0

class test(FloatLayout):
    def w(self):
        a['num'] += 1
        print(a['num'])
        return a

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        d = test()
        Clock.schedule_interval(test.w, 1)
        return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = testApp()
    p.run()


test.kv

#:kivy 1.10.1

<Layout>:
    Label:
        font_size: 200
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos: 415,455
        text: str(root.w()['num'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added one in the form of test.py and test.kv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have several misconceptions:

- If you invoke a function in python it does not imply that the .kv will be called. So if you call the w method with Clock.schedule_interval() it does not imply that the calculated value updates the value of the Label text.
- When you call a function with Clock.schedule_interval you must use the object not a class. in your case, test is class and instead, d is the object.

When you call a function with Clock.schedule_interval you must use the object not a class. in your case, test is class and instead, d is the object.

***.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import DictProperty


class test(FloatLayout):
    a = DictProperty({"num": 0})

    def w(self, dt):
        self.a["num"] += 1
        print(self.a["num"])


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        d = test()
        Clock.schedule_interval(d.w, 1)
        return d


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = testApp()
    p.run()
```

***.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Layout>:
    Label:
        font_size: 200
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos: 415,455
        text: str(root.a["num"])
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. I was able to apply this solution to my main program and it works. So sloppily calling my dict object was the issue?

Comment: @stephenlendl Kivy and many other GUIs live in an event loop so they use certain elements, in the case of kivy the property, to notify the changes. In your case, using a dict does not notify the eventloop of the change, instead a DictProperty does. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]